QGIS custom CRS changes negative eastings to positive westings
I have a situation where I would like to make a custom CRS in QGIS that changes negative eastings to positive westings.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Hi Taona Shumba, welcome to GIS SE. You should give us a bit more information, see [tour] how this site works.

QGIS uses PROJ which support axis directions in the crs definitions. I don't know if QGIS supports them.

As a general rule: load an existing projection and modify it. Copy the CRS definition from the existing one, then in the Options -> User Defined CRS settings create a new CRS and paste the CRS definition. Look for the settings where false easting/northing are defined and change the values.
In WKT format, this can look e.g. like this for false easting of 75° and false northing of -20° (false southing) to get a CRS centered on Indian Ocean:
   PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",-20,
   [...]
   PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",75,

In Proj String format, it looks like this:
    +lat_0=-20 +lon_0=75

Custom Orthographic projection with the mentioned false easting/southing:


Downvoted due to incorrectly using 'false easting' and 'false northing' names for the longitude and latitude of natural origin parameters.

So probably providing correct information would be more helpful?

Maybe? but OP is talking about axis directions, not just changing the origin of a projected CRS.
